# C# How can I make an exception to allow only numbers?

Tags: c#, exception

Here is my Code

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to: 1. play against an Ai or 2. let two Ai´s play aigainst each other?");
Console.WriteLine("Please choose one option!");
 
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("\n");

if (userInput == 1)
{
    // Player
    Player player = new Player();
```

I tried to make an try catch block but then I always got a porblem with `userInput` in my `if` statement. I want a `try .. catch` block to make sure, if the user enters a char or somethingelse (`+`,`~`,`#`,...) they get an *error message* and can enter something new.

Comment: `int.TryParse` and a loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using loop and `if` instead of *catching exceptions* (exceptions have been designed for *exceptional* situations which are not the case - we should validate user input only):

```
   int userInput = -1;

   // Keep on asking user until valid input is provided
   while (true) {
     Console.WriteLine("Do you want to:"); 
     Console.WriteLine("  1. play against an Ai or ");
     Console.WriteLine("  2. let two Ai´s play aigainst each other?");

     Console.WriteLine("Please choose one option!");

     // Trim() - let's be nice and tolerate leading and trailing spaces
     string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

     if (input == "1" || input == "2") {
       userInput = int.Parse(input);

       break;
     }
      
     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid option. Please, try again.");
   }
```

Comment: Why not use TryParse instead?

Comment: Nothing to try. It is only 1 or 2.